# How can i display database data on a Django form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I created a page where the user submits an order. The order is submitted to the SQLite DB and has the following fields: `Time - Status - Rate - UserID`. Once the order is submitted, i would like my django template to show it below an 'Active orders' part of the page.

I don't know how to do it in terms of code, but i figured out that i need to create a query to db where all the user's `orders are fetched (maybe fetching the orders where ID = user's id?).

How would i be able to perform such a operation in Django? In my views?

Here is the template's view:

```
def myview(request):
    item = get_object_or_404(market, item=item)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            send = form.save()
            send.save()
            messages.success(request, f"Success")
    else:
        form = MyForm()

    return render(request,
                  "main/mytemplate.html",
                  context={"form":form})
```

And part of the template:

```
 <form method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% include 'main/includes/bs4_form.html' with form=form1 %}
        <button name="button1" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">BUY</button>
</form>
<h3> ACTIVE ORDERS </h3> 
<p> Here should go the orders... </p>
```

Form:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    status = forms.CharField()
    rate = forms.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ("status", "rate")



    def save(self, commit=True):
        send = super(MyForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            send.save()
        return send
```

Model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    rate = models.FloatField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)


    def save(self): # ALL the signature
        super(MyModel, self).save()
```

Comment: Please, share the code for `bs4_form.html` and also for `MyForm`

Comment: Added it right now

Comment: Your question is confusing. You don't seem to want to display it on the form, but on a separate page. And yes, writing a view and a template are exactly how you would do that; what exactly is your question? Where are you having trouble with writing those?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I did not say i want it to be on another page. This is how it works: the user submits the order form and on the same page, under 'active orders' that data submitted in the order will appear. i just don't know how to 'query' the DB to retrieve that data in django

Comment: But you're not doing anything to record an order as being associated with a user.

Comment: Well, every order is associated to a user via a ID row. When the form is submitted, my model saves the id of the user who submitted it

Comment: Not in any of the code you have shown here. Please post that code.

Comment: I'm sorry, i just added it

Comment: But that doesn't do that at all. You have a field for the user, but you never populate it when you save.

Comment: Why? Once the form is submitted i see the ID of the user who submitted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand your question correctly,
maybe you can try this:

**views.py**

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            send = form.save(commit=False)
            send.user = request.user # set the currently logged in user
            send.save()
    else:
        form = MyForm()

    # fetch it from database then render it to the template
    active_orders = MyModel.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    context = {
       'form': form,
       'active_orders': active_orders
    }
    return render(request, "main/mytemplate.html", context)
```

then, in your template

```
 <form method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% include 'main/includes/bs4_form.html' with form=form1 %}
        <button name="button1" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">BUY</button>
</form>
<h3> ACTIVE ORDERS </h3>
{% for active_order in active_orders %}
<p> {{active_order.time}} - {{active_order.time}} - {{active_order.rate}} - {{active_order.user.id}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```